# running a command as a super user from a Laravel code

Tags: php, linux, laravel, terminal, kannel

So I'm trying to get a process to be run as a super user from within a php code, Usin ssh2 function:

```
$commande='sudo systemctl restart kannel.service';
        $con=ssh2_connect($host,$port);
        $con2=ssh2_auth_password($con,$user,$password);
        if(ssh2_exec($con,$commande)) session()->flash('success','Success!!');
        else session()->flash('success','ERROR');
```

So my question is basically, if I want to run systemctl restart kannel.service as super user that prompts the user for the super user password when required, how should I go about doing this? I have no intention of storing passwords in the script.

```
$commande='sudo systemctl restart kannel.service';
        $con=ssh2_connect($host,$port);
        $con2=ssh2_auth_password($con,$user,$password);
        if(ssh2_exec($con,$commande)) session()->flash('success','Success!!');
        else session()->flash('success','ERROR');
```

I attempted this, but it did not work.

Comment: At what point did your script fail?  What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the streams to blocking mode to ensure the PHP script waits for the command to complete this way you can capture any output/error properly.

```
$command = 'sudo systemctl restart kannel.service';
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password)) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
    $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

    stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

    $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
    $errorOutput = stream_get_contents($errorStream);

    fclose($errorStream);
    fclose($stream);

    if ($output) {
        session()->flash('success', 'Success: ' . $output);
    } else {
        session()->flash('error', 'Error: ' . $errorOutput);
    }
} else {
    session()->flash('error', 'SSH Authentication Failed');
}
```